# Returning multiple arguments from a function

Tags: c

I have written a simple C-program that prompts the user to input numbers and operations as shown in the code below.
I'm stuck on how to pass the user inputs (`&x` and `&y`) to the `result` variable in the main function.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int subtract(int a, int b)

{
        return a - b;
}

int add(int a, int b)
{
        return a + b;
}

int multiply(int a, int b)
{
        return a * b;
}

int (*select_operation())(int, int)
{
        int option = 0, x, y;

        printf("Enter the first number: \n");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        printf("Enter the second number: \n");
        scanf("%d", &y);

        printf("Please select an operation; 1 = subtract, 2 = add and 3 = multiply: \n");
        scanf("%d", &option);

        if (option == 1)
            return subtract;
        else if (option == 2)
            return add;
        else if (option == 3)
            return multiply;
        else
            printf("You entered an invalid operation!");
}  

int main()
{      
        int (*result)(int, int) = select_operation();
        printf("Result = %d\n", result();

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Among other problems, `return subtract;` should be `return subtract(x, y);` etc.

Comment: Read normal books for C and don't try to learn it from forums and other discussions in internet (copy and paste random parts).

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code (`printf("Result = %d\n", result();`). Entering an invalid operation will invoke undefined behavior, since you don't terminate the program; you'll be calling whichever garbage is on the stack (which is even user-controlled through input). You don't check the return values of `scanf` either, so `x` and `y` may contain stack garbage.

Comment: Why do you involve a function pointer at all? You have everything you need in `select_operation`; you can directly execute the operation there and return the result (accordingly, you should perhaps rename it since it does more than just selecting the operation; it also reads the params and would execute the operation). Passing the function (and its arguments, which you're currently failing to do as Vane pointed out) to execute the operation in `main` is just needlessly complicating matters.

Comment: _" have written a simple C-program that prompts the user..."_ - No, it doesn't. This will not compile.

Comment: ...and it's not written simple.

Comment: This code yields 3 errors. A few of them is very clear on what's wrong. Apart from that, when asking a question, you should post the error message if it does not compile. You should also reduce the code to only one specific error.

Comment: `int (*select_operation())(int, int)` I mean, this is syntactically valid but probably the craziest way you could've written that.

Comment: A) Consider using an [`enum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum) rather than mystery numbers which you can easily mix up. B) Don't use function pointers like this, use a look-up table. C) Split *input* and *compute* concerns, you're asking for input inside a function which also figures out how to execute. This is two completely separated jobs.

Answer (score 3):

C doesn't support closures, so the values of `x` and `y` entered in `select_operation` won't be automatically passed to whatever function it returns.

You'll need to pass the addresses of local variables in `main` to this function to have it populate them, then pass those values to `result`.  Also, you need to make sure you return something in all conditions.

```
int (*select_operation(int *x, int *y))(int, int)
{
        int option = 0;

        printf("Enter the first number: \n");
        scanf("%d", x);
        printf("Enter the second number: \n");
        scanf("%d", y);

        printf("Please select an operation; 1 = subtract, 2 = add and 3 = multiply: \n");
        scanf("%d", &option);

        if (option == 1) {
            return subtract;
        } else if (option == 2) {
            return add;
        } else if (option == 3) {
            return multiply;
        } else {
            printf("You entered an invalid operation!");
            return NULL;
        }
}  
int main()
{      
        int x,y;
        int (*result)(int, int) = select_operation(&x,&y);
        if (result) printf("Result = %d\n", result(x,y));

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I finally understood how this works. In C arguments are passed to the calling function by value. To have the main function call the select_operation function passing the user inputs as arguments, we have to pass the arguments by reference. It makes total sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Function pointers have difficult for beginners syntax. I would personally `typedef` the function. Then you can use usual pointer syntax. Also, I would remove the user input from the `select_operation` function.

```
typedef int operation_t(int, int);

operation_t *select_operation(int operation)
{   
    operation_t *func = NULL;
    switch(operation)
    {
        case 1:
            func = add;
            break;
        case 2:
            func = subtract;
            break;
        case 3:
            func = multiply;
            break;
        default:
            printf("You entered an invalid operation!");
            break;
    }
    return func;
}

int main(void)
{      
    int x,y, op;
    operation_t *oper;
    
    scanf("%d", &x);
    scanf("%d", &y);
    scanf("%d", &op);

    oper = select_operation(op);
    if(oper) printf("The result is: %d", oper(x,y));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/b48qE5138

Answer (score 2):

The provided code is not good and does not even compile, as I believe you know.

> I'm stuck on how to pass the user inputs (&x and &y) to the result variable in the main function

Well, you do not even tried to pass them. And `&x` and `&y`  are addresses, not user input. Anyway, to pass them you can easily build and `struct` and put the values inside.

But the idea of the program is good: you have similar functions and a criteria to select the function to use. It is used everywhere in systems programming. A simple example would be a *driver* that receives some sort of data and selects a function to handle the data based on something in the data itself, like a header embedded in the first bytes.

So it is useful to have some example here, I believe.

So an example follows...

### Example

#### output specification

Expected output will be of of these 5 lines:

```
    a - b = c 
    a + b = c
    a * b = c
    Invalid Operation
    Invalid Operands
```

The way you wrote

```
    int (*select_operation())(int, int)
```

is not the way things work. You are declaring a function, but in fact **you want to call the selected operation based on the user input**.

And you should not use logic, `if` commands to select the function to run. You already know at compile time what function to run in each case. e.g. makes no sense check every single time that `1` means `subtract`

this is what you know:

```
    1    subtract
    2    add
    3    multiply
```

`C` was designed to do such things easily.

#### this table in C

```
    // select should be a table, not a function
    int (*VFT[])(int, int) = { NULL,subtract, add, multiply };
```

this is your `select()`, in plain `C`: it is an array of functions pointers that take 2 `int` arguments and return `int`.

the `NULL` is to skip index `0`. The array size is declared `[]` since the compiler is very good at counting the # of itens between `{}`.

This is all we need.

#### one way to pass the values

```
typedef struct
{
    int v1;
    int v2;
    int op;  // 1/2/3 - + * operation
} Values;
```

This was the initial concern: *How to pass user input variables to the main function*

#### one `input` function

```
int input(Values* v)
{
    if (v == NULL) return -2;
    printf("Enter the first number: ");
    int res = scanf("%d", &v->v1);
    if (res != 1) return -2;  // inv operand
    printf("Enter the second number: ");
    res = scanf("%d", &v->v2);
    if (res != 1) return -2;  // inv operand
    printf(
        "\
    Please select an operation:\n\
        1 = subtract\n\
        2 = add\n\
        3 = multiply\n\
\n\
        ==> ");
    res = scanf("%d", &v->op);
    if (res != 1) return -3;  // inv operator
    if (v->op < 1) return -3;
    if (v->op > 3) return -3;
    return 0;
}
```

`input()` gets a pointer to such `struct` and returns `-2` for invalid operand   and `-3` for invalid operation. Or `0` if ok and the operands and operation in the `struct`

#### `main` for a simple test

```
    char what[] = {'?', '-', '+', '*'};  // 1/2/3 are valid
    const char* error[] = {
        "Invalid Operation",
        "Invalid Operand"
    };
    Values v   = {0};
    int    res = input(&v);
    if (res < 0)
    {
        printf("\n\t==> %s\n", error[res+3]);
        return -1;
    }

    // select should be a table, not a function
    int (*VFT[])(int, int) = { NULL,subtract, add, multiply };
    printf(
        "\
\n\
        %d %c %d = %d\n",
        v.v1, what[v.op], v.v2, VFT[v.op](v.v1,v.v2));
    return 0;
}
```

The arrays `what` and `error` supplies the values for the messages, and the execution is just

```
        VFT[v.op](v.v1,v.v2)
```

`input` gets the values. The rest is constant and keept in the 3 arrays `what`, `error` and `VFT`.

No need for `if` for tests, nothing. `C` was created for this.

#### Example of the output

```
Enter the first number: 42
Enter the second number: 17
    Please select an operation:
        1 = subtract
        2 = add
        3 = multiply

        ==> 1

        42 - 17 = 25
```

```
Enter the first number: 42
Enter the second number: one hundred

        ==> Invalid Operand
```

```
Enter the first number: 2
Enter the second number: 3
    Please select an operation:
        1 = subtract
        2 = add
        3 = multiply

        ==> 42

        ==> Invalid Operation
```

#### The complete code for the example

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int v1;
    int v2;
    int op;  // 1/2/3 - + * operation
} Values;

int input(Values*);
int subtract(int, int);
int add(int, int);
int multiply(int, int);

int main()
{
    char what[] = {'?', '-', '+', '*'};  // 1/2/3 are valid
    const char* error[] = {
        "Invalid Operation",
        "Invalid Operand"
    };
    Values v   = {0};
    int    res = input(&v);
    if (res < 0)
    {
        printf("\n\t==> %s\n", error[res+3]);
        return -1;
    }

    // select should be a table, not a function
    int (*VFT[])(int, int) = { NULL,subtract, add, multiply };
    printf(
        "\
\n\
        %d %c %d = %d\n",
        v.v1, what[v.op], v.v2, VFT[v.op](v.v1,v.v2));
    return 0;
}

int input(Values* v)
{
    if (v == NULL) return -2;
    printf("Enter the first number: ");
    int res = scanf("%d", &v->v1);
    if (res != 1) return -2;  // inv operand
    printf("Enter the second number: ");
    res = scanf("%d", &v->v2);
    if (res != 1) return -2;  // inv operand
    printf(
        "\
    Please select an operation:\n\
        1 = subtract\n\
        2 = add\n\
        3 = multiply\n\
\n\
        ==> ");
    res = scanf("%d", &v->op);
    if (res != 1) return -3;  // inv operator
    if (v->op < 1) return -3;
    if (v->op > 3) return -3;
    return 0;
}

int subtract(int a, int b) { return a - b; }

int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

int multiply(int a, int b) { return a * b; }
```